# Caching aerials in a different coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, cache

I have a strange problem to deal with caching of the aerials. All of our Aerials are stored in SDE in State Plane WKID-2237 (NAD_1983_StatePlane_Florida_West_FIPS_0902_Feet). But we are planning to publish all our map services in WGS_1984_Web_Mercator Auxiliary Sphere (WKID-102100) to match up with the ArcGIS online/Bing maps.

What is the best way of caching the aerials in a different coordinate system than that of its source in storage? Transforming it and then storing it is being restricted- partly due to space limitations.

Can I do this by just changing the coordinate system in the Map Document to WKID 102100 and caching it without any Transformations? Are there any pitfalls with this approach?

Comment: Can I do this by just changing the coordinate system in the Map Document to WKID 102100 and caching it without any Transformations?-- you mean just pretend it's in a different coordinate reference?  That's not going to work!

Comment: Can it be interpreted as "Projecting on the Fly"? It's the same way of using data frame's coordinate system while exporting data in a desktop environment!!! What are the pitfalls?

Comment: -- Can it be interpreted as "Projecting on the Fly"?

Comment: -- Can it be interpreted as "Projecting on the Fly"?  I'm not really sure.  I'm not an ArcGIS user.  Looking at the documentation, maybe you are right.  Reprojecting rasters is more of a perf hit than reprojecting vector data, however.

Answer (score 1):

Set the data frame coordinate system (right click on the data frame name, Layers by default, click on properties and choose coordinate system) to the coordinate system that you want to cache (epsg 3857, 102100 is superseded by the now documented 3857) and your imagery from SDE will reproject within your dataframe. When your caching runs it will take that projection. ArcGIS Server 10.1 has a predefined cache scheme (XML) that can assist you with the cache settings

Comment: Thanks for the procedure.But,my question was whether this procedure is the right way to re-project without transformation?